# Azure Devops: How to manually edit an Artifact that has been published by a Build Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

Is it possible to manually edit an Artifact, after it has been published by a Build Pipeline?
I am currently able to Download them, but it seems is not possible to edit.
[Published Artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAgOj.png)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot edit a Published Artifact this way. You can manually edit it if you download it but then you'd have to create another pipeline to publish it.

You should design your pipeline so that the Published Artifact is in the desired state you want it to be in

Comment: Thank you very much David for your answer. What I'm looking for is a way for the pipeline to generate some values, let the user modify them, and then continue the pipeline process (using the modified values). It looks like that's not possible with Published Artifacts. So, is there any other way to achieve this?